# HeidiSQL shows different databases

Tags: mysql, mariadb, heidisql

I would like to show my database in HeidiSQL.

If I start the connection, I see the following databases:

- information_schema
- mysql
- performance_schema
- sys

But in the directory `C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.3\data` I see the following directories:

- mysql
- performance_schema
- test
- **zt_productions**

`zt_productions` is exactly that database that I need. How can I use it in HeidiSQL?

Comment: You probably have a "Database(s)" filter in your session settings? Are you sure you should have sufficient privileges to show that database?

Comment: When you connect, you can see only the databases that you are `GRANTed` permission to see.  `root` (`SUPER`) can see them all.